# code issue adding ELMAH via nuget

Tags: elmah

I added 
ELMAH to my website and i am getting the following error in my web.config
The inheritinChildApplications has a red squiggly meaning the compiler doesnt like it. and the location path portion is grayed out. Im new to using ELMAH, anyone have any thoughts on how to rectify this?

```
 <location path="elmah.axd" **inheritInChildApplications="false"**>
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
  </httpHandlers>
  <!-- 
    See http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages for 
    more information on using ASP.NET authorization securing ELMAH.

  <authorization>
    <allow roles="admin" />
    <deny users="*" />  
  </authorization>
  -->
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="ELMAH" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it does that, but it's not an error as far as I know. It does that on my site and Elmah continues to work just fine.